# trouble compiling rospackage with g2o

Tags: ros, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I am trying to build a basic ros package to do (and optimize) a graph using g2o and data from a robot. The problem is that I can not get to compile even an easy module where I just put few vertices and edges manually (let's say a square) in order to test if I am using propperly the g2o library. I want the latest g2o so I downladed (https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o) and installed it by myself follwing its intructions.

The errors I get when I compile are the following:

- /usr/local/include/g2o/core/block_solver.hpp:446: undefined reference to `g2o::get_monotonic_time()'
- /usr/local/include/g2o/core/batch_stats.h:73: undefined reference to `g2o::G2OBatchStatistics::_globalStats'
- /usr/local/include/g2o/solvers/csparse/linear_solver_csparse.h:126: undefined reference to `g2o::csparse_extension::cs_cholsolsymb(cs_sparse const*, double*, cs_symbolic const*, double*, int*)'
- /usr/local/include/g2o/solvers/csparse/linear_solver_csparse.h:176: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::~MarginalCovarianceCholesky()'
- /usr/local/include/g2o/solvers/csparse/linear_solver_csparse.h:173: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::MarginalCovarianceCholesky()'
- /usr/local/include/g2o/solvers/csparse/linear_solver_csparse.h:174: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::setCholeskyFactor(int, int*, int*, double*, int*)'
- /usr/local/include/g2o/solvers/csparse/linear_solver_csparse.h:175: undefined reference to `g2o::MarginalCovarianceCholesky::computeCovariance(double**, std::vector<int, std::allocator > const&)'
- /usr/local/include/g2o/solvers/csparse/linear_solver_csparse.h:176: undefined reference to `cs_nfree'

I obviously skept the parts of the error message where it points to my code.

My CMakeList.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${EIGEN_DEFINITIONS})

set(g2o_DIR /usr/local/bin/g2o)
include_directories(/usr/local/include/EXTERNAL/csparse)
include_directories(${G2O_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

rosbuild_add_executable(g2o_mvm src/g2o_mvm.cpp)
```

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68251/trouble-compiling-rospackage-with-g2o/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

G2O_INCLUDE_DIRS is not defined previously, as mention. So, we have corrected as follows:

SET(G2O_LIBS g2o_cli g2o_ext_freeglut_minimal g2o_simulator g2o_solver_slam2d_linear g2o_types_icp g2o_types_slam2d g2o_core g2o_interface g2o_solver_csparse g2o_solver_structure_only g2o_types_sba g2o_types_slam3d g2o_csparse_extension g2o_opengl_helper g2o_solver_dense g2o_stuff g2o_types_sclam2d g2o_viewer g2o_ext_csparse g2o_parser g2o_solver_pcg g2o_types_data g2o_types_sim3 cxsparse )

rosbuild_add_executable(g2o_mvm src/g2o_mvm.cpp)
target_link_libraries(g2o_mvm ${G2O_LIBS})

In ubuntu, g2o can be installed directly from the repository (ros--libg2o), however we have built it from the source code.

---

Originally posted by [juandhv](https://answers.ros.org/users/5509/juandhv/) with karma: 16 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2013-07-24**:
Thanks! That totally solved the problem!